# Sequelize Model/Model info missing from Exceptions

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is it only my incompetence, or sequelize stores no information about what Model generated an exception in it's exceptions?

For instance, if a UniqueConstraintError/SequelizeUniqueConstraintError is thrown due to an unique key being violated, where inside this exception can I find an instance of the Model responsable? A dynamic reference (instance) would preferable, however, even a static reference would help.

There's plenty of SQL and SQL-related data, but that doesn't help me much.

I'm running Sequelize v6.7 on Node.js v14.17.5.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: UniqueConstraintError has `errors` collection each of its elements has `instance` prop with a model instance. Please check them

Comment: Will do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

UniqueConstraintError has errors collection each of its elements has instance prop with a model instance. Please check them